# Bayes theorem with multiple conditions

Tags: probability

how to calculate P(a|b,c,d). knowing that b, c and d are NOT independent from each others ?

i know how to solve it if there is independency assumption. however, i am just wondering if there is any approach to tackle this problem

Comment: You will need to know some probabilities to evaluate this conditional probability.  Please state the definition of this conditional probability so that Readers are aware that you know the definition.

Comment: for this sake, we use a subjective probability weights (for d , b and c)  which are usually inherited from knowledge engineering. these three event are all aggregate together in the posterior event (a) in order to evaluate its truth value. however, it’s unlikely to know the probability weight of all prior events.

Comment: My point was just that the definition of conditional probability tells us one way to "calculate", namely if we know $Pr(a\cap b\cap c\cap d)$ and $Pr(b\cap c\cap d)$, then take their ratio.  Whatever else one might do to compute the conditional probability depends on knowing something about probabilities of events and their intersections.